# Speed issue with Slic3r and Marlin

Tags: marlin, slic3r

I am trying to print with clay.

These are my Slic3r speed settings,

[image: Slic3r speed settings]

Other information;

- Nozzle: 1.4 mm
- First layer height: 0.9 mm
- layer height: 1 mm
- Filament dia: 1.8 mm
- perimeter: 3

When I print, the first layer is printed faster than remaining layers and in the remaining layers, the two inner perimeters are printed much slower than the outer perimeter.

- Video: [print video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UE2MFhjTXpVEirsNK3KlALi4Fb5Ca8rX)
- G-code: [gcode](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GMyNPaX8YiB3-P2UNHGC3gTZC3M3oilm)

Isn't this strange since I give the same print speed for all?

Comment: My impression was that clay requires a much larger nozzle.  Do you really mean clay as in  riverbed sediment?

Comment: can you please turn your gcode into plain .txt by just changing the file type?

Answer (score 1):

No, you did not set all the settings to the same speed, there are 2 different print speeds defined:

- Infill Solid: **60** mm/s
- First Layer Speed: **30%**

This means, that some walls will be printed 10 mm/s faster than the others, and that *first layer* should be printed at 30% of 50 mm/s, so at 15 mm/s - try to define it as a speed. Make sure to save and apply the settings and only *then* slice your model, as you might have sliced the model with the previous settings.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that on the Print Settings tab, under Advanced, you have set the Extrusion widths for your custom nozzle settings.